# PHP: how to mark a radio button as checked on pageload?

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for an attribute like `checked="checked"` for checkboxes which i can echo out in php..

Comment: when you say "on pageload", you're not referring to the `load` event in JS. Or are you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be `checked="checked"`

Comment: ah got it, it was because i have multiple forms using the same "name" attribute one one page

Comment: ok im just gonna use php rand() to stop inputs overriding, as its admin side. thanks

Comment: you do know you're talking by yourself?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML solution:**

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel" value="" checked="checked" />
```

Please note, that the actual value of checked attribute does not actually matter; it's just a convention to assign "checked". Most importantly, strings like "true" or "false" don't have any special meaning.

If you don't aim for HTML conformance, you can simplify the code to:

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel" value="" checked>
```

I hope its helpful for you